# In d3, how do I include text and a background box as I roll over my line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, background, rect

I'm using d3 v4.  I want to display some text corresponding to where folks are mousing-over my line chart and I would like to have a background box on this text.  So I'm trying this

```
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  var rect = focus.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("fill", "yellow");

    ...

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.index_date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
    rect.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.value));
  }
```

but what is happening instead is there is just a rectangle without any text floating over my mouseover point as you can see here -- https://jsfiddle.net/xx77tzn3/9/.  How do I adjust what I have to include the text and a background box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<svg>`'s (rather unintuitively) don't allow you to append `text` elements to `rect` elements. Uncomment

```
//var text = focus.append("text")
```

and comment out:

```
var text = rect.append("text")
```

Then it the mouse function, change line 113 to this:

```
focus.select("text").text(formatCurrency(d.value));
```

Then it's just a matter of formatting the text on that `<g>`.

**EDIT**: in order to format the text to be **on** the `rect`, you need to make the coordinates of the text relative to the `<g>`, not the `rect`. I.e.:

```
var text = focus.append("text")
  //var text = rect.append("text")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 10);
```

Now the text is there, *and* on top of the rectangle.

[Updated js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8reo2Lvc/)

Comment: Yeah but then I don't have a background for my text.  I want my cake AND I want to eat it.  Mmmm, cake.

Comment: @Dave you do, but the text isn't on it. It's like the cake falling off the plate (T-T)

Comment: Haha, any way to keep in on there?

Comment: @Dave there sure is. Check out the [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8reo2Lvc/).